# Cascading Dropdown in Mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using Mvc3 I have 2 dropdown,BankBranch and city.
On first time load of view i am binding both the dropdon without cascading. then if user select city i want to change bankbranch according to that.
I am confused how i can achieve both the things together.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This blog post should get you on your way.  It provides examples for normal form posts, microsoft ajax form post, jquery ajax and others.

http://weblogs.asp.net/raduenuca/archive/2011/03/06/asp-net-mvc-cascading-dropdown-lists-tutorial-part-1-defining-the-problem-and-the-context.aspx

**EDIT:
Generalized Code Explanation**

Model

```
public class CascadeModel {
    public SelectList<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public SelectList<BankBranch> BankBranches { get; set;}
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
}

public class Branch {
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult BranchSelector() {
     var viewData = new CascadeModel();
     viewData.Cities = new SelectList(Repository.GetAllCities(), "Id", "Name", selectedCity);
     viewData.BankBranches = new SelectList(Repository.GetBranchesByCity(selectedCity), "Id", "Name", "");
     return View(viewData);
}

public JsonResult GetBranches(int id) {
    return Json(Repository.GetBranchesByCity(id), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

View:

```
@model CascadeModel


@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CityId, Model.Cities, new { style = "width:250px" })
<br />
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BranchId, Model.BankBranches, new { style = "width:250px" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#CityId").bind('change', function() {
             $.ajax({
                 url: '/Controller/GetBranches/' + $(this).val(),
                 success: function(data) {
                     //Clear the current branch ddl
                     //Load the new Branch data returned from the jquery call in the branches ddl
                 }
             });
         };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: hi Michael,Thanks for the reply. I had read it before but this is not what i want to do.

Comment: Which part is not what you want to do?  If you are coming from an asp.net web forms background the mvc way will be quite different and in my opinion more elegant.  Let me know what doesn't work for you and I will try to get you in the right direction.  Thanks,

Comment: Yes you are right im new for mvc. I want 2 dropdowns which are filled in view load time then i want to apply cascading on same dropdown. Means on selection of 1st dropdown user should get 2nd ready to select or even user not select value from st dropdown then also there some value in second that he can select.

Comment: I updated the with generalized example.  Using Jquery ajax call